# getFailedLoginAttempts() function doesn't make any sense in appfoundation in Vaadin

Tags: java, authentication, vaadin

How to get failed login attempts using appfoundation? It has a function getFailedLoginAttempts() but it doesn't make any sense. I am using Vaadin 6 (6.8.12)

My code is here:

```
NativeButton login = new NativeButton(Lang.getMessage("login"), new ClickListener() {

         private static final long serialVersionUID = -5577423546946890721L;

         public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

             username = (String) usernameField.getValue();
             String password = (String) passwordField.getValue();
            try {
                AuthenticationUtil.authenticate(username, password);            
                startApp();    
            } catch (InvalidCredentialsException e) {
             /* I need to get failed login attempts here but how can I do that? 
I just can by doing this: AuthenticationUtil.authenticate(username, password).
getFailedLoginAttempts(),  but I need to write try and catch blocks 
(so try and catch blocks in catch block) for authenticate method and this
function will never work, because user won't be authenticated and all 
the time you will go to the other catch block; */
                feedbackLabel.setValue(Lang.getMessage("usernameOrPasswordIncorect"));                    
            } catch (AccountLockedException e) {
                feedbackLabel.setValue(Lang.getMessage("accountBlocked"));
            }
        }
    });
```

I wrote all the problem in the comment. I want to print a number of failed login attempts but can't get this number. Any suggestions?

Comment: what version of vaadin are you using

Answer (score 0):

Why the code `AuthenticationUtil.authenticate(username, password).
getFailedLoginAttempts()` compiles is that the `authenticate` method returns a User object upon successful authentication and this method can then be accessed.  However if an exception is throws then you do not have  the User object.  In their unit tests then use a FactoryFacade to retrieve the user object and check it that way.  I do not know the API well so I can not tell you whether you can get the user some other way.

see https://code.google.com/p/vaadin-appfoundation/source/browse/src/org/vaadin/appfoundation/authentication/util/AuthenticationUtil.java

Comment: I implemented getUserForUsername(String username) method from AuthenticationUtil.java in my own class and solved the problem in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for getting user in my own class.

```
private User getUserForUsername(String username) {
    String query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = :username";
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    parameters.put("username", username);
    return (User) FacadeFactory.getFacade().find(query, parameters);
}
```

And call this method in catch block.

```
try {
    AuthenticationUtil.authenticate(username, password);
    startApp();
} catch (InvalidCredentialsException e) {
    User user = getUserForUsername(username);
    feedbackLabel.setValue(Lang.getMessage("usernameOrPasswordIncorect"));
    attemptsLeftLabel.setValue(Lang.getMessage("attemptsLeft", 5 - user.getFailedLoginAttempts()));
} catch (AccountLockedException e) {
    feedbackLabel.setValue(Lang.getMessage("accountBlocked"));
}
```

All works fine.